# Generalisation for k independent paths

Tags: graph-theory

I was studying graph theory and came across this problem:

> Show that a graph with $n > 3$ vertices and $m > \frac{3(n - 1)}{2}$
>   edges contains two vertices joined by three independent paths.

I was wondering whether the following generalisation could be proved:

> Show that a graph with $n > k > 0$ vertices and $m > \frac{k(n - 1)}{2}$ edges contains two vertices joined by k independent paths.

My reasoning was that, for $k = 1$, we have $n > 1$ and $m > \frac{n - 1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow m \geq 1$, resulting in at least one edge in the graph, which means that there is at least one pair of vertices joined by a path (the ones connected by the edge). Moreover, for $k = 2$, we get $n > 2$ and $m > n - 1$, which means that there is at least one simple cycle in the graph. Every pair of vertices that are part of the cycle are connected by at least two independent paths (those consisting of the cycle's vertices). For $k = 3$, we get the aforementioned problem.

Is it possible to prove this for every positive integer k?

Comment: Where did you get the first result?

Comment: The first result can be found as an exercise in various graph theory books, including Modern Graph Theory by Bollobas. Also, a few days after I posted my question back in May, I found out that, actually, the generalization I refer to above is indeed correct and can be found in books such as Extremal Graph Theory (also by Bollobas).